# Android wear packaging 1 compatible device

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, wear-os

I had an app uploaded in google play, but now I have done a update with Android Wear. I have my project in Android Studio with the mobile and the wear APK in the same project and with the same package. It runs perfectly in debug mode. I can export the new update of my app with the Android Wear app embebed, but when I upload it with the Google developer console shows that there are only one compatible device.

Attached Images:

[image: Problem with compatible devices]

[image: Wear gradle]

[image: Mobile gradle]

How can i make my wear app to be compatible with more than 1 device? :-)

Comment: change your compile and target sdk version to 19 in your mobile app

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do it. If I change my compile and target sdk version to 19, then appears this message:

Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'.

I think It's because this function is only available in 20 sdk. I can't delete it because it reappears.

And If I try to change de minSdkVersion to 19 the message is:

Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0

Comment: The sdk version 19 should be changed in your MOBILE Manifest, not the WEAR Manifest, so you can still use the wearable library in your v20 wear app.

Comment: It doesn't work... I have 20 SDK int he wear App, and 19 SDK in the mobile oneo, but still only one compatible device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have the permission `android.hardware.type.WATCH` in the Play Store permissions.

This is only required for the *wear* application.

Remove it from your `AndroidManifest.xml` *mobile* application, it looks like:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```